# A very annoying NSPredicate crash on iPhone 5 and iPad 4th gen with iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

As title of this question says, below my code is crashing when `NSPredicate` is initializing. So far i found out that crashing is occuring only on iPhone 5 and iPad 4th gen with iOS 10.3.
On other devices with the same iOS 10.3 everything is OK.

```
func getPredicate(for serviceId: Int64, startingFrom step: Int) -> NSPredicate {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "serverID == %i AND step == %i AND type == %@", 
                                serviceId, step, "button")
    return predicate
}
```

This [blog post](http://aplus.rs/2018/core-data-nspredicate-crash/) perfectly describes my problem, and I also have the same crashing problem on 32 bit CPU devices.
Although the solutions given in the post helped me to stop crashing, but `CoreData` always returned `nil` result when I used it in fetch requests.

Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Development Tools:

- XCode version: 11.2.1
- Swift Language Version: Swift 5
- Devices: iPhone 5 and iPad 4th gen

Answer (score 1):

The `%i` format is for formatting a value of the C `int` type, and that is a 32-bit integer on all current iOS platforms. Passing a 64-bit integer instead (in your case: `serviceId`) is undefined behavior and can cause a crash.

The correct format for a 64-bit integer is `%lli` (for `long long int`), and the correct format for an `Int` (which can be 32-bit or 64-bit) is `%li` (for `long int`).

So this works on both 32-bit and 64-bit devices:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "serverID == %lli AND step == %li AND type == %@",
                            serviceId, step, "button")
```

An “easier” way is to convert all numbers to `NSNumber`, because you don't have to remember the correct formats for the various integer types. `NSNumber`s are “objects” (instances of an Objective-C class), and can simply be formatted with the `%@` format:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "serverID == %@ AND step == %@ AND type == %@",
                            serviceId as NSNumber, step as NSNumber, "button")
```

Passing the arguments as an `argumentArray` *may* work by chance, but with the wrong formats it is still undefined behavior.